# Build error: NuGet package Assembly Reference Error

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I am trying to run “XamlControlsGallery” example of Microsoft.

The Project has a reference to:

- **ColorCode.UWP** package

...which in turn is dependent on:

- **ColorCode.Core** package.

I downloaded NuGet packages for both, because I am working on an offline environment. I installed them to the solution, but I am getting the error:

> you must add a reference to assembly ‘ColorCode.Core…’ .

I can see the declarations of the types which give error with Ctrl+LeftClick.

I tried:

1. the solution that deletes all the packages and re-installs them
2. I also tried deleting .vs folder and things under .nuget/packages folder, and let VS find the packages
3. I tried editing .vsproj file adding  `<reference include=“ColorCode.Core”/>`, but it could not find the assembly, probably because it is not in the global assembly cache, and giving hint path also did not work.

Nothing worked, the error is still there.

My packages:

```
ColorCode.Core 2.0.8
ColorCode.UWP 2.0.5
```

Comment: Manage NuGet Packages-> package source: my local package dir->clicking install for all the packages @MickyD

Comment: _"probably because it is not in the global assembly cache"_ - NuGet by its very nature doesn't use the GAC

Comment: I forgot to write that, but I also tried to copy the “colorcode.core.dll” under output folder and tried to add it as a reference to the solution, but it says “you cannot add it as a reference because it has been done automatically” as you said. I can navigate to the files that have the declarations with ctrl+leftclick, so it is not a namespace error I think. There is no namespace called Core under ColorCode namespace anyway.

Comment: Try using **ColorCode.Core** version **2.0.5**.   (ColorCode.UWP depends on ColorCode.Core (>= 2.0.5)) just in case _someone moved my cheese in 2.0.8_

Comment: Using ColorCode.Core version 2.0.5 is the solution. Thank you.

Comment: Oh sweet.  Good to hear.  Yeah NuGet and backward compatibility is like _rolling the dice_ sometimes :)